# Select multiple boxes at random instead of a single box - HTML / JS

Tags: html

I'm new to coding, and I'm trying to make a game.
The Game:
**There are 9 blue boxes. Out of those 9 boxes, 4 random boxes will be orange.
The 4 orange boxes will be different, every time the page is refreshed.
Clicking on any orange box, will turn it blue.**
(There is more info on the game, But I'll stop here to keep it simple.)
I have tried this code to change 4 boxes from blue to orange: `` <script> function getRandomInt(min, max) {   min = Math.ceil(min);   max = Math.floor(max);   return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min); } const boxNumber = getRandomInt(1, 9); document.getElementById(`box${boxNumber}`).style.backgroundColor = ("#D4A108") </script> ``. However, when I use this, Only one box becomes orange. Clicking on the single orange box will turn it blue, But I dont want a single orange box. How do I make my code turn 4 boxes orange at random? ***My Full Code***:

```
<style> 
#box1 {
  position: relative;
  border-top-left-radius: 80px;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid grey;  
}
#box2 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid grey;  
}
#box3 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 80px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid grey;  
}
#box4 {
  position: relative;
  left: 215px;
  bottom:678px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid grey;  
}
#box5 {
  position: relative;
  left: 215px;
  bottom:688px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid grey;  
}
#box6 {
  position: relative;
  left: 215px;
  bottom:698px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid grey;  
}
#box7 {
  position: relative;
  left: 430px;
  bottom:1355px;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  border-top-right-radius: 80px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid grey;  
}
#box8 {
  position: relative;
  left: 430px;
  bottom:1366px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid grey;  
}
#box9 {
  position: relative;
  left: 430px;
  bottom:1377px;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 80px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid grey;  
}
</style>


    <p type="button" id="box1" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(8, 174, 212);" onclick="setColor(event)" ;="" data-count="0">
</p><p type="button" id="box2" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(8, 174, 212);" onclick="setColor(event)" ;="" data-count="0">
</p><p type="button" id="box3" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(8, 174, 212);" onclick="setColor(event)" ;="" data-count="0">
</p><p type="button" id="box4" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(8, 174, 212);" onclick="setColor(event)" ;="" data-count="0">
</p><p type="button" id="box5" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(8, 174, 212);" onclick="setColor(event)" ;="" data-count="0">
</p><p type="button" id="box6" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(8, 174, 212);" onclick="setColor(event)" ;="" data-count="0">
</p><p type="button" id="box7" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(8, 174, 212);" onclick="setColor(event)" ;="" data-count="0">
</p><p type="button" id="box8" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(8, 174, 212);" onclick="setColor(event)" ;="" data-count="0">
</p><p type="button" id="box9" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(8, 174, 212);" onclick="setColor(event)" ;="" data-count="0">

  <script id="JSColor">
    function setColor(e) {
  var target = e.target,
  count = +target.dataset.count;

  target.style.backgroundColor = count === 1 ? "#08AED4" : '#08AED4';
  target.dataset.count = count === 1 ? 0 : 1;

}
</script> <script>
function getRandomInt(min, max) {   min = Math.ceil(min);   max = Math.floor(max);   return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min); }
const boxNumber = getRandomInt(1, 9);
document.getElementById(`box${boxNumber}`).style.backgroundColor = ("#D4A108")
</script>


</p></body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function setColor(e) {
  var target = e.target,
  count = +target.dataset.count;
  target.style.backgroundColor = count === 1 ? "#08AED4" : '#08AED4';
  target.dataset.count = count === 1 ? 0 : 1;

}

function getRandomInt(min, max, nbBoxeOrange) {
  // create a array of number from min to max
  let tabBoxeIdCanBeOrange=[]
  for(i=0;i<=max-min;i++) tabBoxeIdCanBeOrange.push(min+i)
  // apply a random sort and return a slice from 0 to nbBoxeOrange
  return tabBoxeIdCanBeOrange.sort((a, b) => 0.5-Math.random()).slice(0, nbBoxeOrange)
}
const boxNumber = getRandomInt(1, 9, 4);
boxNumber.forEach(element=>{
document.getElementById(`box${element}`).style.backgroundColor = ("#D4A108")
})
```

```css
#box1 {
  position: relative;
  border-top-left-radius: 80px;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid grey;  
}
#box2 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid grey;  
}
#box3 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 80px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid grey;  
}
#box4 {
  position: relative;
  left: 215px;
  bottom:678px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid grey;  
}
#box5 {
  position: relative;
  left: 215px;
  bottom:688px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid grey;  
}
#box6 {
  position: relative;
  left: 215px;
  bottom:698px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid grey;  
}
#box7 {
  position: relative;
  left: 430px;
  bottom:1355px;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  border-top-right-radius: 80px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid grey;  
}
#box8 {
  position: relative;
  left: 430px;
  bottom:1366px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid grey;  
}
#box9 {
  position: relative;
  left: 430px;
  bottom:1377px;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 80px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid grey;  
}
```

```html
    <p type="button" id="box1" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(8, 174, 212);" onclick="setColor(event)" ;="" data-count="0">
</p><p type="button" id="box2" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(8, 174, 212);" onclick="setColor(event)" ;="" data-count="0">
</p><p type="button" id="box3" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(8, 174, 212);" onclick="setColor(event)" ;="" data-count="0">
</p><p type="button" id="box4" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(8, 174, 212);" onclick="setColor(event)" ;="" data-count="0">
</p><p type="button" id="box5" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(8, 174, 212);" onclick="setColor(event)" ;="" data-count="0">
</p><p type="button" id="box6" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(8, 174, 212);" onclick="setColor(event)" ;="" data-count="0">
</p><p type="button" id="box7" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(8, 174, 212);" onclick="setColor(event)" ;="" data-count="0">
</p><p type="button" id="box8" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(8, 174, 212);" onclick="setColor(event)" ;="" data-count="0">
</p><p type="button" id="box9" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(8, 174, 212);" onclick="setColor(event)" ;="" data-count="0">



</p></body>
```